# Call Window.Close() event for chrome and Opera from Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-chrome

As we know to close current browser tab for Chrome we can use the following code

```
    var win= window.open("","_parent",'');
    win.close();
```

I have tried this code in this way

```
    function closeMe() {
       var win = window.open("", "_parent", '');
       win.close();
    }
```

and invoke it like this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="BTN" runat="server" Text="close the window" OnClientClick="closeMe()" />
```

works like a charm for both Chrome And opera.

However I am trying this code to call it from codebehind c#, in this way:

```
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "keyname", "var win = window.open('', '_parent', '');win.close();", true);
```

But unfortunately it is not firing up..
Is their doubles quotes which are missing or Javascript has not been invoked properly? synatx alright?
Can any one help me please.?

Comment: tried this as well, not working.. Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "keyname", "<script type='text/javascript'> var win = window.open('', '_parent', '');win.close();</script>", true);

Answer (score 0):

By security reasons chrome not allowed this.

Comment: Ir requires 4 arguments so i tried this
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "keyname", "var win = window.open('', '_parent', '');win.close();", true); not working :(

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ var win = window.open('', '_parent', '');win.close(); }, 1000);

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "keyname", "setTimeout(function(){ var win = window.open('', '_parent', '');win.close(); }, 1000);", true); not working :( Can u please check it on ur end??

Comment: Im my case your code not working. Chrome not allow this.